# Performance of WPF TreeView Refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, treeview

I have a background worker that I use to populate a collection that my TreeView is bound to. I have the GUI display a progress dialog while the backgroundworker is running. I close the progress dialog in the RunWorkerCompleted event of the backgroundworker. This all works nicely and as expected.

The problem is that often the TreeView still takes a while to update after the progress dialog has closed. Sometimes a lot of data has been added to the TreeView so it can take up to 10 seconds or so to refresh. This causes frustration and confusion in the users.

- Why does the TreeView refresh take so long?
- Is there a way to speed it up?
- Or to know when the refresh/redraw is finished so I can close the progress dialog then instead of when my backgroundworker completes?

Update: I have virtualization turned on.

Comment: What kind of collection is your tree bound to? How complex is your item template? Can you describe how your TreeView and ViewModel are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to performance profile your application?
There are a couple of tools out there to help you do this. They will let you see what methods are being called for you update process and you may be able to spot some still executing code for the update process.

Links
http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

http://www.yourkit.com/

http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/